# Randomly factor a number into exactly three factors

Tags: python, factorization

I've been over the available questions and answers, and none of them really apply to my situation, so here goes.

I'm working in python and trying to factor the number 1800 into three random factors. I'm not really concerned about the format of the output. I would be okay with a tuple, a list, or even three separate variable numbers. Neither am I concerned about making all of the factors similarly valued. My output could be 2,2,450 or 12,15,10 or anything else.

My best thought was to use the prime factorization (2,2,2,3,3,5,5), create three random subsets, and multiply the items in each subset together. I've looked into multiple methods, and they all appear to have some issues.

`ShuffleSplit` from scikitlearn will only give me indices of values. So I have to split, get the values into the two lists and then split a second time and put the values into the two new lists. That turns into a lot of lines of code.

Using `randint` will allow me to find a sublist of prime factors, put that one aside, find another sublist of the remaining prime factors, and then multiply each list out. This is only partially random because I'd have to determine how many factors I want to go into each list.

I could use `itertools.permutations` (or some other permuting function) to generate a randomly ordered list of the factors and then slice that list manually into three lists. This has the same concern as the `randint` method in that I have to specify how many small prime factors are included in each of my three output factors.

Listing all possible combinations of factors and randomly choosing one isn't really time feasible.

What's a good (quick, simple, and potentially scalable) way to do this with Python?

Comment: *"Listing all possible combinations of factors and randomly choosing one isn't really time feasible"* - Why not? There aren't that many.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you already have written the code for generating primes and factorization. If not, there is code on the web in less than 200 lines.

So you have a list of list of primes e.g., `[2,2,2,3,3,5,5]`

Rather than go down the path you've suggested, I think you would do better to use random sample as it doesn't replace the numbers used. You know the first number can be as large as the number of prime factors, minus two (because you have to have two more numbers). The second number would come from the set of random samples that would be either 1 (if there were just two remaining numbers or a random number between 1 and the number of remaining numbers, minus 1 (because, again, you have to have at least one more number to make up the three)

This will get you the first set of numbers. I think you can see where to go from there.

```
import random

prime_factors = [2,2,2,3,3,5,5]

def rand_factors(lst):
    elem_for_first_factor = random.randint(1, len(prime_factors)-2)
    return [k for k in random.sample(prime_factors, elem_for_first_factor)]
```